# 405 (Method Not Allowed) laravel 5 for ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5.1

In my website page I am displaying some vendor details with search filter and review. I am implementing review using ajax which works fine.
But when I use search filter to display vendors city wise I use different url but display result on same page at that time review ajax doesn't work.

It shows ***405 (Method Not Allowed)*** exception

***Step1:*** For display vendor details I used following url

```
Route::get('/packersearch', 'User@getPackers');
```

on `packers.blade.php`. At this moment my ajax for review works fine but when I insert city name in search filter it uses following url

```
Route::post('/moverssearch','User@moverSearch');
```

which dislays result on same `packers.blade.php`. After using search result when I tries use same ajax review it shows **MethodNotAllowedHttpException**.

Why I am getting this error.Please Help me

my ajax

```
 $("#rating").click(function(){        
    var rate = $("input[type='radio'].rate:checked").val();        
    var title=$("#title").val();

    var review=$("#review").val();        
    var token=$("#token").val();
    var id=$("#id").val();        

   var dataString ="rate="+rate+"&title="+title+"&review="+review+"&id="+id;  

    $.ajax({                                  

      url: "vendorReview",                 
     type: "POST",
     beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN',    $("#token").attr('content'));}, 
      data:dataString,         

      success:function(res){
        console.log(res);

        if(res)                        
        {
          $('#msg').modal('show');

        }

      }//success

    });//ajax

  });//click function
```

Answer (score 5):

**405 Method Not Allowed**

This means that you have a `GET` route handler while you are trying to `POST` a request or vice versa.

Check if you do have same request setup for the ajax:

```
Route::post('/vendorReview','User@moverSearch');
//----^^^^^------check this in the controller method.
```

My assumption says that you have a `get` there like:

```
Route::get('/vendorReview','User@moverSearch');
//-----^^^------check this in the controller method.
```